# How can I gain access to a parent class's private variable?

Tags: java

I understand that private variables aren't inherited, so how can I gain access to it in my subclass?

i.e

```
 class A{
    private int i = 5;
    // more code
 }
 class B extends A{
    public int toInt(){
        return super.i;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You don't. They wouldn't be private if you had access to them...

Comment: You can always use getters/setters (public/protected methods), if you absolutely have to. But I see no reason why you would require that.

Comment: yeah the problem is i have this assignment where i have to gain access to them.. thanks iMan i'll give that a try :)

Comment: You either need to make `i` protected, or you need to make a public (or protected) getter-method. I would make the getter.

Comment: "private variables aren't inherited" - this is not precise - they actually *are* inherited, but they remain inaccessible/unvisible to sub classes.

Comment: Are you sure you understand the assignment correctly? Can you post the actual text? I wouldn't expect reflection introduced to learners ... teaching them how to write brittle code.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you'd mark `i` as `protected` which allows sub-classes to see the field.

Another approach is to write a `get`-style function, which sometimes can be better especially if you want to disallow sub-classes from writing to the field. Writing a `put`-style function really defeats encapsulation.

*Reflection* also offers another way of circumventing `private`, but using that approach is not to be recommended.

Comment: You can use set with a private modifier, or none to limit encapsulation breach.

Comment: @JustinMiddleton mark this as the answer to be fair (if it solved your problem, and it looks like ).

Comment: I would add that this is possible if `A` and `B` are nested classes of the same outer class.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can't and should not. This is the reason that the variable is `private`.

If you want to implement your base class to allow its subclasses to get access to the private members implement `protected` accessor methods (either getters or setters). You can also mark the fields as `protected` but I do not recommend even to start with it. You need very serious reason to make non-private fields.

The "workaround" that is possible in java is using reflection API:

```
Field f = A.class.getDeclaredField("i");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.get();
```